# Codeigniter : Trying to get property of non-object of row()

Tags: php, codeigniter

The error:

[image]

here's my code:
[image]

```
function get_modal_awal(){
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
     $sql = "SELECT modal_awal
             FROM trans_modal_awal 
           WHERE date_format(tanggal,'%Y-%m-%d') = '".date('Y-m-d')."'
           AND kode_kasir = ".$_SESSION['kode_user']."";
     return $this->db->query($sql)->row()->modal_awal; //the error goes here
 }
```

my view code like this:

```
<input readonly class="form-control" type="text" id="modal_awal"name="modal_awal" value="<?php echo $modal_awal;?>"></input>
```

**my controller:**

```
$data['modal_awal'] = $this->Modal_kasir_model->get_modal_awal();
```

What should I do?

Comment: Was it more hard to write the code here?????

Comment: Can you paste the code as text please? Anyone wanting to test or edit this now has to type it in again.

Comment: @BenHillier post edited

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Do not share a screenshot but put directly your log error too or someone will ask you : «Was it more hard to write the log error here?»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that your SQL always returns a row. If it doesn't, then there is no object to read. I would try to trap this:

```
function get_modal_awal(){
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $sql = "SELECT modal_awal
            FROM trans_modal_awal 
         WHERE date_format(tanggal,'%Y-%m-%d') = '".date('Y-m-d')."'
         AND kode_kasir = ".$_SESSION['kode_user']."";

    //Get row
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    if($result){
        $row = $result->row();
        if($row){
            //return row if set
            return $row->modal_awal;
        }
    }
    //return nothing, and deal with it in the calling code
    return false;

}
```

It's also not a bad idea to wrap your SQL calls in a `try ... catch` block.

Comment: Just about. Replace the `return false;` in the above function with `return '';` and you'll get an empty `input` box when the query returns nothing. You also need to put a space before _name_ in the template `id="modal_awal"name="modal_awal"`

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_modal_awal()
{
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $sql = "SELECT modal_awal
    FROM trans_modal_awal 
    WHERE date_format(tanggal,'%Y-%m-%d') = '".date('Y-m-d')."'
    AND kode_kasir = ".$_SESSION['kode_user']."";
    $res = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $res->row('modal_awal');
  }
```

Use above code

Comment: If the query is invalid, won't this still throw the error? `$res` will be null.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: put result in variable and return that variable  ex : $val = $res->row('modal_awal'); return $val;